# Array targeting trouble in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Brand new to programming so I apologize in advance.

I'm trying to set up a game where after each time a button is pressed, a new instance of a MC is added to stage, then I need a collision detection for an existing object with any of the new instances of the MC. I need to add one instance to the stage at a time and once it reaches 8 instances, I need it to stop adding children but still be able to detect collisions with any of the instances. As it stands now it just replaces the MC or MCs into the new random position. Heres what my code looks like so far:

```
var pinkBox:pinkClass = new pinkClass();
var pinkArray:Array = new Array();


myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownleftBtn);{
    function mouseDownleftBtn(e: Event): void {
        for(var i=0; i<8; i++)
{

addChild(pinkBox);
pinkArray.push(pinkBox);
pinkBox.x = Math.random()*stage.width;
}    
myButton.startDrag();
        }
    }

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkCollision);

function checkCollision(event:Event){


if (myButton.hitTestObject(pinkBox)) {

    trace("hit")
}}
```

Comment: I see at least 1 problem that you don't create pinkBox every time you want to add a new one, but address the only instance instead. Also, format your code because unformatted code could easily hide structural and logical mistakes.

Comment: Ok I moved   var pinkBox:pinkClass = new pinkClass();  into the mouseDownleftBtn function. Now its creating new instances but the collision detection only works on one of those instances.

Comment: ...because you only test collision with the one box that is in the **pinkBox** variable, instead of looping through **pinkArray**.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!